Baseboard heater connection to Pex Pipe Corrosion
What I'm showing is the unfinished wall behind the drywall. The pipe connects to a small bathroom baseboard heater (hot water boiler system). The pipes for the heating element look just fine on the other side. However, on the reverse side this is what's going on. Not actively leaking but rather it is sweating or seeping through the connection up top. Not sure how long this has been happening. I've been here 2 years only.
I was quoted 1100 to fix this and that seemed absurd. Waiting on other quotes but want to understand the possible scope of work. Even if the heating element had to be replaced the part is less than 100 bucks so I'm a bit confused on the how and why of this. What would be the fix here?
I want to fix this ASAP but what preventive measures can I take in the meantime? Can this burst? The boiler is off for a few weeks now and I don't see the water seeping out much anymore. Just want to avoid the entire boiler system leaking out into my basement.


For the cost you were quoted we can assume that the plumber considered other components in jeopardy. You're asking us to assess something we can't see in this photo. There are no "preventative measures" as the leak will just get worse until the parts are replaced (which you can certainly do if you're willing).

"Sweating or seeping" is actively leaking, just slowly, unless the "sweating" is condensation on a COLD pipe, which seems unlikely in a Heating pipe. So, fix the leaky connection.
The corrosion on the pipe looks remarkably bad. Might as well replace it when fixing the leak. Might be a failure to remove corrosive flux after soldering, aggravated by the slow leak. Some folks are prone to use corrosive flux on non-potable systems such as heating loops.
